# Find start and end date in java

Tags: java

I have a list of String consisting of dates in a particular format say dd-MM-yyyy . I need to traverse the list and find out the start date and the end date in this list using java.
Example-

```
list is-{22-12-2008,12-12-2009,21-12-2005,12-12-2008}
```

i shld have my result as start date is - `21-12-2005` and end date is `12-12-2009`.

Comment: Have you tried yourself first?

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). So once you have parsed the dates, you can use Comparable to sort them (either using [`Collections.sort(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) or a via a sorted collection like a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html))

Comment: I was just about to post the same answer.

Comment: oh hey thanx i didn know that date also implements Comparable

Comment: i was thinking of getting date.Year and so on and then compare everything

Comment: @justin3250 java.util.Date makes it very hard to do that. If you want to do that, use JodaTime instead. But you shouldn't, unless you actually need the individual data fields.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the first date is both start and end date, traverse the list of dates and match the next date in list with start date, set the start date to next date in list if next date is smaller than the start date. 
Perform the similar match for endDate but set the value of endDate if date in list is greater

Pseudo code:

```
set startDate = list[0];
set endDate = list[0];

for i = 1 to Size of date list
    if ToDate(list[i]) < startDate
       startDate = ToDate(list[i])
    end if

    if ToDate(list[i]) > endDate
       endDate = ToDate(list[i])
    end if
end for
```